# php inside echo tags

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, categories, sidebar

I am running a wordpress website and I am trying to echo out different sidebars according to different categories but I can't seem to put php code inside the echo tags. The code is working fine to echo out different content, in the sidebar, on different category pages but I just can't add php code inside echo ' ' as it's returning an error. This is my code:

```
<?php  if ( is_active_sidebar( "main_sidebar" ) ) :  ?>

     <div id="main_sidebar" class="widget-area">
               <?php
               if ( is_category( '7' )) {
               echo 'Sidebar to be echo'd on category page with ID=7';
               }
               else 
               {
               echo 'Sidebar to be echo'd on all the other category pages';
               }   
               ?>
     </div><!-- #first_sidebar .widget-area -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

and this is how I want it to function:

```
<?php  if ( is_active_sidebar( "main_sidebar" ) ) :  ?>

     <div id="main_sidebar" class="widget-area">
               <?php
               if ( is_category( '7' )) {
               echo '<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'category_fashion' ); ?>';
               }
               else 
               {
               echo '<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'main_sidebar' ); ?>';
               }   
               ?>
     </div><!-- #first_sidebar .widget-area -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

I am getting this error when using the above code:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
>   in /home/ignoremu/public_html/wp-content/themes/.../sidebar.php
>   on line 6

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: in this line  echo 'Sidebar to be echo'd on category page with ID=7'; there is a (')  on echo'd try to put the entire echo string within ("") like echo "Sidebar to be echo'd on category page with ID=7";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method for you is to skip HTML in your echo completely and just output the result with the echo as such:

```
<?php  if ( is_active_sidebar( "main_sidebar" ) ) :  ?>

     <div id="main_sidebar" class="widget-area">
               <?php
               if ( is_category( '7' )) {
               echo dynamic_sidebar( 'category_fashion' );
               }
               else 
               {
               echo dynamic_sidebar( 'main_sidebar' );
               }   
               ?>
     </div><!-- #first_sidebar .widget-area -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, it's working like a charm now but there's a little problem. There's this digit '1' appearing under the sidebar widget area, you can check it over here: http://ignoremusic.com/category/modelcitizens/. It's only appearing when I am echoing the sidebar using conditional tags, otherwise when the sidebar on all the pages are same, the digit '1' is not appearing.

Comment: @FahadHasan the 1 should not appear. It's probably caused by the category_fashion and so much the shown code.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to put single quotes inside an echo with single quotes, you will have to escape the quotes:

```
//                      Escaped here
echo 'Sidebar to be echo\'d on category page with ID=7';
```

Same goes with double quotes inside double quoted strings.

EDIT: oops, didn't read fully. To fix your problem change:

```
if ( is_category( '7' )) {
    echo '<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'category_fashion' ); ?>';
} else {
    echo '<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'main_sidebar' ); ?>';
}
```

To:

```
if ( is_category( '7' )) {
    echo dynamic_sidebar( 'category_fashion' );
} else {
    echo dynamic_sidebar( 'main_sidebar' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already in php why to start php again ? Just below will work.

```
echo dynamic_sidebar( 'category_fashion' );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately I cannot vote up right now as my reputation is still under the 15 mark but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If dynamic_sidebar() is a function, why do you need to echo it, instead of returning/echoeing value inside the function, so calling it, will return value by the given param